# Environment variable JavaScript

Tags: npm, environment-variables, package.json, parcel

Hi I have this package that I don't want parcel to install it automatically it is @parcel/transformer-sass and I found out that I could do that with environment variable.

This one `process.env.PARCEL_AUTOINSTALL = 'false'`

Well problem is that I have no idea what environment variable is, nor where should I put it in order to work. I searched a bit on google and it all seems confusing to me. So if someone can just tell me where to put this line of code in order to work I will appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One solution, the one I know and find more "elegant", is to use .env files. You are probably already using that configuration system, check your project folder.
The solution would be something like this:

```
# .env
PARCEL_AUTOINSTALL = false
```

If you have problems with data types, try using [dotenv-parse-variables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-parse-variables)

If you are not using .env files yet, I suggest you this post [Node.js Everywhere with Environment Variables!](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786)